# Heroku toolbelt won't run on windows 7 user with non-latin chars in it

Tags: windows, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

It's a late Sunday night and I decided to mess around with Facebook applications. Turns out they now offer you easy integration with heroku which, of course, I decided to try out.
I patiently waited for the toolbelt to download, installed it and, as usual, nothing will run for me without bit of a struggle.

So I did what I could, googled the problem I'm having and realized that the problem is most likely caused by the fact that my user folder contains non-latin characters. 
To make sure that this is the problem, I created another user account, installed heroku toolbelt on it and it works just fine.

Are there any suggestions on how to get this to run without me having to work on the test account?

Thank you for your time!

**edit**

Forgot to ask wether it's possible to change the folder heroku uses?

**edit**

Still haven't found anything that would help me fixing this, is there really no way how to fix this?

*I've attached the screenshot of error*

[image: Error I'm receiving]

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled on this post while being in much the same position.  Here goes a solution:

Edit `...\Heroku\lib\heroku\helpers.rb` such that `def home-directory` is as follows:

```
def home_directory
  running_on_windows? ? (ENV['HEROKU_HOME'] || ENV['USERPROFILE']).gsub("\\","/") : ENV['HOME']
end
```

Now if you set the `HEROKU_HOME` environment variable to anything the Heroku toolbelt will use that as home.  (FWIW: As I have run into this with other tools as well, I set up a link with US-ASCII-only letters to my standard home directory under `Users`.)

Comment: I also sent a [pull request on Github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/pull/810)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is run the **`heroku login`** command from the **Git Bash** client rather than from the default Windows command line. I have been using the heroku-toolbelt on Windows 7 for about a year now and have not encountered any such problem whatsoever. I had found a way to enable latin characters in the Windows command line sometime ago writing a program in CLIPS, but I don't quite remember how the command goes right now, or what configurations I did. However, if you don't have the standalone Git client installed you can always grab it from: http://git-scm.com.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sadly the exact same problem still persists. I am sure, at this point, it's my accounts folder that is causing the problem.

http://i.imgur.com/hpfZ6.png

Comment: Which version of the heroku toolbelt are you using? I've read somewhere that **`version 2.32.13`** has some sort of bug and it produced similar errors, but **`version 2.32.14`** works. However, I'm using **`version 2.34.0`** which is the most current. So try that and let me know.

Comment: I am running 2.34.0 as well. Re-downloaded and installed the toolbelt just to make sure, and still am experiencing the same problem.